# Styling coordinates in QGIS's Map Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Is it possible to achieve the following style for coordinates in a map grid in Map Composer?

[image: Example]

Comment: but it is more. one thing is to override the style, the second thing is to move the coordinate (override the position). the example is moved to the left of the tick.

Comment: In a single custom labelling expression `concat(left(@grid_number,2),
replace( substr(@grid_number,3,99)  ,array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'),array('¹','²','³','⁴','⁵','⁶','⁷','⁸','⁹','⁰'))
)` - you'll need to cut and paste the superscripts if you cant enter them on the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks a lot Spacedman, if you put this as an answer I will accept this.

Comment: Cant answer as this is marked as a dupe. I could add it as an answer to the dupe though, it might be useful there as it uses pure expressions....